Azure Node JS web app CI CD is too slow through Github CI CD
Here is my CI CD pipeline to build and push the next js web app to Azure Web App Service.
Current pipeline literally takes 30 minutes to be precise for deployment. Most of the time is for deployment.
Build -> 3min. 20 sec.
Deploy -> 26min. 37 sec.
I am not able to figure out how to solve this issue of zipping and deploying the package. In prior times i have done directly to VM's using PM2 and it was super quick. Need help to speed it up for Azure Web Apps.
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - name

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - staging
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    env:
      NEXT_PUBLIC_HOST: ${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_HOST }}
      NEXT_PUBLIC_REDIRECT_URL: ${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_REDIRECT_URL }}

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '20.x'

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build
      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip -r release.zip .next/ * -x "*.git*"
            
      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: release.zip

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'nextstaging'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_F1C1 }}
          package: .


Can you share your github repo if poosible

it's private repo @SirraSneha

Refer to this SO thread once.

@SidKaushik, add the application setting  WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1  in your Web app=>Environment Variables and deploy again.

The reason for slow deployment is due to Kudu takes the ZIP it receives, then extracts it, and copies all files into /home/site/wwwroot.
Node's node_modules folder contains thousands of files, that causes deployment to be slow.
To speed up the process, add the application setting WEBSITE_RUN_FEOM_PACKAGE=1 in the App Service=>Environment variables as mentioned in GitHub issue.
This setting will deploy the app service to read only file system (read-only for wwwroot folder)

I have deployed a Nodejs application using GitHub actions and it took 44s to deploy.
GitHub Workflow:
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - app

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '18.x'

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
          npm run test --if-present
      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./* -r

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: release.zip

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'app'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_31396XXXDC3 }}
          package: .

Application Settings of App Service:

Deployment Status:


Massive improvements, thanks for the solution :). It still took me 5 minutes but much better than 30 minutes. My artifact size was 250MB, maybe cause of that ?

if you do zip deployment, then i get this error as well:
Error: Cannot find module '../server/require-hook'
Require stack:
/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/next
at Module._resolveFilename
It's like next is not readable from wwwroot zip

Can you share your GitHub repository if possible?

I can't share it, that's private, but i can share specific things if you are looking for something else

Can you delete node_modules folder and try again?

Just to note that you have a spelling error in your answer 'FEOM' should be 'FROM' in case someone copy-pastes from the text. In the image it is correct.
